# Efficiently check if all the values of columns are null (or equivalent)

Tags: performance, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (1910 columns) which in some columns contains only null (or equivalent) values. I want to have a list of all those columns whose null count value is = 3103276687 (equal to row count).

As the number of rows and columns is huge, I need a highly optimized query. Otherwise my Databricks notebook runs for hours at stretch and sometimes doesn't generate results.

I want the list of columns where all the rows are null, so that I could drop them.

P.S: don't give answers using `collect()`, it's an expensive function.

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, isnan, when, count

df_5 = df_2.select([count(when(col(c).contains('None') | \
                               col(c).contains('NULL') | \
                               (col(c) == '' ) | \
                               col(c).isNull() | \
                               isnan(c), c 
                          )).alias(c)
                    for c in acceptedColumns ])

nullColumns = []

totalcount = df_2.count()

for col in accpetedColumns:
    if(df_5.select(col).collect()[0][0] == totalcount):
        nullColumns.append(col)

print(nullColumns)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that `any` would perform better than `count`. However, `any` is not available in Python API, so `expr` is needed.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df_5 = df_2.select(
    [expr(
        f"""
        !any(
            case when {c} is null or
                      {c} = 'NULL' or
                      {c} = 'None' or
                      {c} = '' or
                      isnan({c})
                 then true
                 else false
            end
        ) as {c}
        """) 
     for c in acceptedColumns]
)
df_6 = df_2.select([c for c in acceptedColumns if df_5.head()[c]])
```

`df_6` is already filtered - it does not have columns containing only null values.

BTW, you have a typo in `accpetedColumns`. In this code, I have changed it to `acceptedColumns`.